# dbf file insertion Take a long Time

Tags: c#, oledb, dbf

I  use OLEDB to insert data to a DB4 .dbf file. Inserting 13 row takes almost 1 minute which is soooo long, this problem only occurs during insertion in one table, that contain a varchar 20, 2 dates and a decimal. Is there any alternative faster ways to do this?

```
 foreach (DataRow row in fstathotel.Rows)
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"insert into fstathote values (" + Convert.ToInt32(row["mpe"]) + ",'" + Convert.ToDateTime(row["date"]) + "','" + row["type"].ToString() + "',?,'" + Convert.ToDateTime(row["edate"]) + "')";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmSlot1", Decimal.Parse(row["value"].ToString()));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: show your insert code

Comment: I used a DataTable to start the data and i loped throught the Datable with a foreach a dataRow

Comment: I suppose, somethis wrong with your db, it shouldn't take that time. Try to make step-by-step debug and see the time, each operation takes. And try to make the combined text query with all 13 inserts, and see the results

Comment: I did , I debuged hte code , the direct insertion work just fine, incredibly fast, I can't see where is the problem ! any other idea ??

Comment: I do not know about DB4. Have to tried to enclose your loop in a transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` in the loop.

This means a parameter is added at each iteration. I do not know about DB4, but I would bet that the OleDB drivers is trying to handle extra additional unused parameters the best it can. It succeeds, but the operation take much more time.

Please insert `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` like this, and tell if things are running better.

```
foreach (DataRow row in fstathotel.Rows)
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"insert into fstathote values (" + Convert.ToInt32(row["mpe"]) + ",'" + Convert.ToDateTime(row["date"]) + "','" + row["type"].ToString() + "',?,'" + Convert.ToDateTime(row["edate"]) + "')";
    cmd.Parameters.Clear(); // Clear the parameter list 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmSlot1", Decimal.Parse(row["value"].ToString()));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Additionally, I would also try to enclose the loop in a database transaction. Remember that too much indexes on the table are bad for insertion performances.

Comment: Thanks Lot , this insertion are way faster than before